# On Xcode 8.2 I keep receiving error “No accounts with iTunes connect access”

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, xcode8

I know so many people have asked this question already. But their work around is not working for me.

I tried deleting my account from pane again and again. Created new certificates and then tried cleaning project too before archiving. But still I am getting this error.

I did open itunesconnect using my credentials. Just after it checks for user with certificate during validation i am getting this error.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Download Xcode 9 GM seed, then create Archive using the Xcode 8.3 and once the Archive is done. Open Xcode 9, validate and upload. This will work.